# Is it possible to control SSRS from coding?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to manipulate SSRS reports from any programming language. I mean to add custom columns to the table from coding itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notionally you can build and modify any SSRS report with any language that can produce XML (so anything that can amend a file).  I've not seen it done and would love to see some concrete examples as further answers.  However, here is the Microsoft resource on the topic which includes a link to a .Net walkthrough: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179499(v=sql.80).aspx